# Validez de un certificado

Tags: ssl

Como puedo comprobar que un certificado sea válido. Y no me refiero solo a que no haya expirado sino también a la validez de la marca que hay detrás, ¿En qué certificados debería confiar y en cuales no?.

Por ejemplo Lets encrypt permite a todo el mundo crear un certificado por lo que su validez no es tanta. ¿Cuáles son los mejores valorados y en los que debería confiar?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La validez de los certificados ssl (en cuanto a que sean de fiar) depende de varios factores:

- Que no esté autofirmado.
- Que no esté caducado.
- Que esté emitido para el dominio al que accedes.
- ...

Todo esto son requisitos que cualquier herramienta de verificación de certificados ssl puede facilmente resolver.

No obstante lo más importante es la confianza. Para ello lo que debes decidir es si confías en la Autoridad Certificadora (CA) que firma el certificado.

Hay muchas CA globalmente aceptadas (COMODO, LetsEncript, DigiCert, Amazon, etc.). Parte de toda validación ssl incluye verifricar que tengamos instalados los certificados de esa CA (es decir, que confiamos en ella).

Todos los navegadores y sistemas operativos tienen un almacen de estos certificados.

En el mundo empresarial, por ejemplo, muchas empresas crean sus propias CA de modo que todos sus equipos confien en los certificados emitidos por ellos mismos.

Al respecto de LetsEncrypt o cualquier otra autoridad de certificados, lo importante es qué validaciones realizan.

- Validación de propiedad del doiminio.
- Validación del propietario.
- Validación del negocio.

Las últimas son más complicadas ya que requieren verificación humana por las que las empresas cobran unos buenos precios, pero también son las más "de fiar" e incluyen por ejemplo la "Barra verde" en los navegadores.

LetsEncrypt realiza una validación automática del dominio, pidiendote que demustres la propiedad del dominio. Por tanto sus certificados te sirven perfectamente para verificar que un servidor que te dice que es "example.com" es legítimo.